# Where is the list of the types of exceptions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Please help me find the official documentation with a list of the types of  of exceptions. I wrote this action:

```
def show
  begin
    @user = User.find(params[:id])   
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
    logger.debug e
    logger.debug "Error #{$!}"
    render_404      
  end
end
```

I need to mention several types of exceptions:

```
def show
  begin
    @user = User.find(params[:id])   
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
    logger.debug e
    logger.debug "Error #{$!}"
    render_404  
  rescue anotherExceptionType1 => e   
    ......
    ......
    ..... 
  rescue anotherExceptionType2 => e   
    ......
    ......
    ..... 
  rescue anotherExceptionType3 => e   
    ......
    ......
    .....         
  end
end
```

but I did not find the list of exceptions in the documentation.

Comment: Make clear the namespace. Do you only want those within `ActiveRecord`?

Comment: Why are you trying to rescue these exceptions if there is no need to?

Comment: For AR, See http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActiveRecord & `RecordNotFound` http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActiveRecord/RecordNotFound

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can see all the subclasses of ActiveRecordError here:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/errors.rb

Answer (score 11):

I can give you a list of exceptions but I am not sure if that is what you really want. Instead you probably want to figure out which exceptions will be thrown in your specific case. More importantly you probably should not be rescuing exceptions to begin with. For more information take a look at [this link](http://daniel.fone.net.nz/blog/2013/05/28/why-you-should-never-rescue-exception-in-ruby/)

However you asked for a [list](http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2006/09/06/rubys-exception-hierarchy/) so here you go:

- Exception
- NoMemoryError
- ScriptError
- LoadError
- NotImplementedError
- SyntaxError
- SignalException
- Interrupt
- StandardError
- ArgumentError
- IOError
- EOFError
- IndexError
- LocalJumpError
- NameError
- NoMethodError
- RangeError
- FloatDomainError
- RegexpError
- RuntimeError
- SecurityError
- SystemCallError
- SystemStackError
- ThreadError
- TypeError
- ZeroDivisionError
- SystemExit
- fatal

You can visit the link to find a hierarchy of the errors as well.

Comment: but this list is not ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound.It means the list is not complete

Comment: @stackov8 Downvoted your question because of your comment. Where is it written that you want `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`? Don't say it is in the example.

Comment: @sawa The question is tagged with Ruby on Rails. ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound is an exception, and it's not in the list.

For Ruby core though, it seems this list is complete.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly, here is the list of available exceptions.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Exception.html

Answer (score 1):

#### There is none.

The reason for that is you can implement your own exception, effectively making any such list invalid.

As for the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`: **you shouldn't rescue it** most of the time, as Rails will rescue it and serve a standard 404 response which by default renders `public/404.html`.

Unless it's an "allowed failure". If that's the case, you shouldn't be using `find`, use `find_by_id` instead that will return `nil` if the given record was not found, **without raising exceptions**.

Other exceptions typically indicate a serious failure in your application (like database dropping dead or network starting living a life of its own). Normally, your application should raise none. In an event something serious happens and you're absolutely certain that this request cannot be processed, raise an exception: it will bubble up and turn into `500 Internal Server Error` response.

You should prevent exceptions from being raised during normal execution of your application.

Comment: Thank you for addressing the _real_ problem to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Get all classes that inherit from Exception:

```
exceptions = ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select{|c| c < Exception  }
```

Print:

```
exceptions.map(&:to_s).sort.each{|s| puts s}
```